# XML Schema cvc-complex-type

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

I have been trying to clear this issue up, at this point I am unsure if i'm messing up the namespaces which is causing the issue or if it is something wrong with the syntax of the code but all instances  of itemName are declared the same and are all closed correctly.

Trying to figure out this error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'itemName'. One of '{itemName}' is expected.
```

My xsd file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

targetNamespace="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe"
xmlns="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe"
>


        <xs:element name="recipe">
           <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="itemName" type="xs:string" />
                 <xs:element name="ingredients">
                   <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="ingredient" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="ingredient" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="ingredient" type="xs:string" />
                     </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                  <xs:element name="directions" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

       </xs:element>
```

The XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<recipe 
xmlns="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/chestershartland/recipe recipe.xsd"
>

  <itemName>Oatmeal Breakfast</itemName>
  <ingredients>
     <ingredient>1/3 c steel cut oats</ingredient>
     <ingredient>1-1/4 c water</ingredient>
     <ingredient>1/4 t salt</ingredient>
  </ingredients>
  <directions>
  <![CDATA[Bring water to a boil. Add salt and oats, stir, and lower heat
     to lowest setting. Cover and let stand 2 hours.
  ]]>
  </directions>
</recipe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the parenthesis, and use `*` to indicate 0 to n occurrences on the container element:

```
...
<!ELEMENT images (img+)>
<!ELEMENT img EMPTY>
...
```

To your question: its element content is empty, but it can still have attributes.

Comment: When i do that, the errors are "the content of element type "images" must watch "(img)".

Comment: that's what you declare - check my edited answer for fix

Comment: if it is still not what you want, it helps if you also share a sample XML

Comment: The user said _"I have to create the images element, containing *one or more* img elements..."_ So you'd want to use the `+` occurrence indicator; not `*`.